# how to add a number onto a variable name and cycle upward: x1 x2 x3 etc in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, cycle

I need to change a variable name each time a piece of code loops, and increment it by one.

I'm not sure how to append it onto the variable name, so in my example each time it loops ( once for each div that's a  direct child of body ) it assigns a new variable name --> myFunction1 myFunction2 myFunction3 and so-on.

Here's what i have:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('body > div').each(function(i) {
                    alert(i);
                    // for each carousel
                    function myFunction+i(carousel) {
                        // whatever
                        })
                    };
                    });
            });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with these functions? I'm fairly confident that whatever it is, you're going about it the wrong way. (No offense! :) I just want to help solve the problem, this kind of stuff is hackish IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you would do that, but it can be done like this:

```
window["myFunction"+i] = function(){...};
```

assuming you want these functions to be global.  Then it can be called as normal:

```
myFunction1();
```

Comment: so i just declare each variable with the top line you gave me there, ad then i can use the functions as normal. i'll give it a try - thanks!

Comment: the reason i was needing to do this is there are 17+ carousels on my one-pager site and i need to declare a new carousel for each one. trying to avoid 17 instances of the following:

http://pastebin.com/YtaDhRyk

Comment: I'm willing to bet there's a better way using `this` and DOM traversal  in place of hard-coded `id`s to find the correct elements for the given carousel.